# Date and Time with play framework?

Tags: date, time, model, playframework

I want to separated fields in my model: actionDate and actionTime. Can I use the datatypes sql.Date and sql.Time for this? Or should I use util.Date for both?
What's the correct way?

Thanks a lot,

joe

Comment: Did you actually Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util.Date is probably the right choice. However, the question is why do you want a separate date and time in your model. A better pattern would be to have a single Date object that contained the date and time, and if you need setters/getters to interrogate the separate parts of the date/time, then you can do so.

There is nothing to stop you from using setters/getters in Play.

Comment: How do you mean that? Should i make a setTime() and a setDate()-method? And both of them are editing the date-object in my model? And how does it work than with my form and the validation?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your form would reference `time` and `date`, and as a result, the code would call `setTime` and `setDate`, but you would then set the value to your underlying date object.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use java.utils.

EDIT: OK, to clarify, java.utils.Date is the one used (commonly) with Play Model.